# Getting from datatype string hexadecimal to INTEGER hexadecimal type in Python

Tags: python-3.x, integer, hex

I'm having an issue getting from hexadecimal string to hexadecimal integer in Python 3.

When you write hex(12) you get the output 0xc which is a str class. However, when you type fx. int = 0x55 the class/type is an INTEGER.

How do you go from "0x55" to 0x55 (as an integer)

Thank you :)

Comment: Clarification: I don't want 0x55 as the decimal 85, I want 0x55 as an integer type, this only seems possible when doing:  variable = 0x55   where it is then treated as  an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting confused between the concepts of a number's representation and a number's value. For example, the following evaluates to `True` in Python: `83 == 0o123 == 0x53` The decimal representation is 83, and octal representation is 123, and the hexadecimal representation is 53. However, the value of all those representations are the same. For the sake of explanation, I will give you the value using the decimal representations; the value is 83.

If you are trying to convert a string into a number, you may want to look at the `eval` and `ast.literal_eval` functions. Here is a demonstration of how you might use the second:

```
>>> number = 12345
>>> hex_string = hex(number)
>>> oct_string = oct(number)
>>> print('hex_string =', repr(hex_string))
hex_string = '0x3039'
>>> print('oct_string =', repr(oct_string))
oct_string = '0o30071'
>>> number == ast.literal_eval(hex_string)
True
>>> number == ast.literal_eval(oct_string)
True
>>>
```